# Get a page's last modified date using Java

Tags: java, date, html

Is there a standard way to tell when a page was last modified?  Currently I am doing this:

```
URLConnection uCon = url.openConnection();
uCon.setConnectTimeout(5000);   // 5 seconds
String lastMod = uCon.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
System.out.println("last mod: "+lastMod);
```

However it looks like some sites do not have a `Last-Modified` field.

http://www.cbc.ca has these header fields:

```
X-Origin-Server
Connection
Expires
null
Date
Server
Content-Type
Transfer-Encoding
Cache-Control
```

I could parse a page to try and get its date but this seems like a major pain.  What is the standard?

*(If possible I would like to stick with using URLConnection because that is what I use to download the webpage)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard. Dynamically generated web pages generally do not have a Last-Modified field, and different web pages include dates in different ways. Some sites do not even include such a date, including "© <current year>" at the bottom. You could try looking for a date near the bottom or the top, but *reliably* extracting the date from the web page would have to be site-specific.

Comment: huh, that is what I thought too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From [HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> 14.29 Last-Modified
>
> The Last-Modified entity-header field
>   indicates the date and time at which
>   the origin server believes the variant
>   was last modified.
>
> ```
>    Last-Modified  = "Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date
> ```
>
> An example of its use is
>
> ```
>    Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT
> ```
>
> The exact meaning of this header field
>   depends on the implementation of the
>   origin server and the nature of the
>   original resource. For files, it may
>   be just the file system last-modified
>   time. For entities with dynamically
>   included parts, it may be the most
>   recent of the set of last-modify times
>   for its component parts. For database
>   gateways, it may be the last-update
>   time stamp of the record. For virtual
>   objects, it may be the last time the
>   internal state changed.
>
> An origin server MUST NOT send a
>   Last-Modified date which is later than
>   the server's time of message
>   origination. In such cases, where the
>   resource's last modification would
>   indicate some time in the future, the
>   server MUST replace that date with the
>   message origination date.
>
> An origin server SHOULD obtain the
>   Last-Modified value of the entity as
>   close as possible to the time that it
>   generates the Date value of its
>   response. This allows a recipient to
>   make an accurate assessment of the
>   entity's modification time, especially
>   if the entity changes near the time
>   that the response is generated.
>
> HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD send
>   Last-Modified whenever feasible.

From this point `Last-modified` is optional and its value depends of the nature of the original resource.