# Recrawling only changed pages of a website using Searcharoo

Tags: web-crawler

I am using Searcharoo for crawling a webstie. During recrawl I only want to crawl those pages which are updated after a particular date. How to do this? The site I am crawling is not a blog or a news site. It is a review site. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to re-crawl when content changed or when the resource on the server changed?

Comment: I want to schedule a crawl process on particular interval, say 10 days. While recrawling I want to crawl only those pages which were modified after my previous crawl event.

Comment: According to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060246/get-a-pages-last-modified-date-using-java), there is an http field for last modified but my guess is that implementation is spotty. You might therefore just consider saving the raw page html and doing a string comparison with the last time you searched it.That way you at least don't pull down the assets. Just a thought!