# How to get online file's last modified date?

Tags: android, html, file, date, last-modified

I am writting an app for my college and it should alert user when some changes have occured on college's websites. The problem is that I can't change these websites, only read them; yet they don't have "last-modified" in html header.

For now I compare them by downloading the whole html code, then making MD5 checksum out of it, thus seeing if something has changed. But there should be some better(faster) way, or not?

Comment: do they have etag headers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: No, they don't. Can I ask server somehow to give me a last modified date of html file?

Comment: You can add header If-Modified-Since, but in your case I think it won't have an effect since Last-Modified is not returned. It should be configured on web server to avoid downloading file each time

Comment: This question looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060246/get-a-pages-last-modified-date-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can check md5 on server every 5 seconds and then just answer for little file with true/false result)).
Also you can connect to servers with ftp and check files status if you have access to it.
I also find this [guys](http://www.changedetection.com/) - they sends notifications when choosed site has changed.

But i think your variant is much easer). 
What is wrong with it? To much time spent for the check?

Comment: Yeah, well I guess I'm gonna have to do it this way. It does get slow sometimes when user wants to follow more than 6,7 pages and is using a mobile network.